# pytesseract not recognizing symbols in front of letters

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

Trying to use pytesseract to read a few blocks of text but it isn't recognizing symbols when they are in front of or between words. It does however recognize the symbols when they are in front of numbers.

Example:

`'#test $test %test'` on the image prints wrong `'Htest Stest Stest'`

`'#500 $500 %500'` on the image prints correct `'#500 $500 %500'`

Here is my code:

```
    import cv2
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image

    image = cv2.imread("test.png")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    threshold = 225
    _, img_binarized = cv2.threshold(image, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(img_binarized)

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

    msg = pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_img)
    print(msg)
```

I have played around with a bunch of different config settings in the `image_to_string` call but haven't found anything that works, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading all the .traineddata files from https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files.html to my `Tesseract-OCR` folder and looping through all of them using the language parameter of `image_to_string`. For some reason a few select languages that share the same alphabet as English worked just fine (Italian and Croatian worked best).

My code is the same as above but language is adjusted:

```
msg = pytesseract.image_to_string(pil_img, lang='ita')
```